# How to implement the following operation in pytorch (tensor by equating indices)

Tags: python, tensor, neural-network

I wasn't sure if I should post this on stackoverflow rather than here, but because I have to construct a specific tensor I think here is more suitable.

I have 2 tensors, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N \times L}$, and $d\in \mathbb{R}^{M \times L}$ my goal is to construct a new tensor defined as
$(\cdot,\cdot) : \mathbb{R}^{M \times N \times L} \times \mathbb{R}^{M \times L} \to \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$

defined as

$$
(x,d)_{ij} = \sum_{1 \leq l \leq L} x_{ijl}d_{il}
$$

the closest thing I've found is the pytorch function [tensordot](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensordot.html)

However given the following example

```
x = torch.tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],[ 4,  5,  6],[ 7,  8,  9]],[[ 2,  4,  6],[ 8, 10, 12],[14, 16, 18]]])
d = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2]])
z = torch.tensordot(x,d,([2],[1]))
```

gives me the tensor

```
z =
tensor([[[ 6, 12],
         [15, 30],
         [24, 48]],
        [[12, 24],
         [30, 60],
         [48, 96]]])
```

Which corresponds to the formula

$$
z_{ijk} = \sum_{1 \leq l \leq L} x_{ijl}d_{kl}
$$

to get the result I want I just have to take

$$
(x,d)_{ij} = z_{iji}
$$

But I struggle to find an API that does this in pytorch, but I am sure there is one, I just don't know what to search for.

I've tried "trace" but I find only the trace of a square matrix.
Does therefore anybody know if this operation has a name or how I can implement it using pytorch primitives without maybe resorting to for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it might be convenient to perform the entire calculation with Einstein summation:

```
torch.einsum('ijl,il->ij', x, d)
```

This then directly computes the sum that you wrote down in your question and (up to transposition) yields the same solution as `torch.diagonal(z, dim1=0, dim2=2)` from @Vladimir Lysikov's answer.

Comment: Can this be used for tensor products? Suppose you have $A_{ij}$ and $B_{klm}$ two tensors. Then would we be getting with your call $C_{ijklm} = A_{ij}\times B_{klm}$?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, you could also use this for tensor products, e.g. `torch.einsum('ijl,km->ijlkm', x, d)` for the tensor product of `x` and `d`. (Alternatively, you could use torch.kron(x,d) but this stores the solution slightly differently then you want, e.g. the Kronecker product of two matrices is a very large matrix and not a rank-4 tensor.)

Comment: More generally, the benefit of using `torch.einsum` is that you you can explicitly write down your tensor operations and don't need to write down the sums, since you automatically sum over repeated indices, as in my answer. The physics notation equivalent of `torch.einsum('ijl,il->ij', x, d)` is $c_{ij} = x_{ijl}d_{il}$, where the repetition of the index $l$ signifies that we mathematically have $c_{ij} = \sum_l x_{ijl}d_{il}$.

Comment: Technically you have also a repetition of `i` as well in the example. But understand. Just out of curiosity is it also possible to construct, for example, 4D tensor from 2 2D tensors like $(a_{ij},b_{kl}) \to a_{ij} - b_{kl}$?

Comment: I replied to your new question and that should hopefully resolve this comment

Answer (score 2):

I don't have PyTorch installed to check, but from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diagonal.html) it seems that `torch.diagonal(z, dim1=0, dim2=2)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What I did at the end was something like

```
z = torch.tensordot(a,b,dim=[[2],[1]])
z = z[1:M,:,1:M]
```

where `M` is the common dimension size of the tensor `z` coming from the first line